# Why are visa decisions confidential?

Tags: visas, schengen

Please explain why visa decisions kept confidential?

Please also explain why in many countries such as UK, Europe, they wont tell the outcome of the decision of visas by phone or email even to the applicant? Why one has to appear to visit the consulate in person to know the outcome of the visa decision?.

Why cant they relax the confidentiality with visa decisions?

Comment: How would they know they're talking to the applicant on the phone and not an imposter? I'd also imagine that consulates simply don't want to deal with the extra emails and phone calls to give out information: they have a well-defined process and they follow it.

Comment: well! they can verify date of birth with passport data they have. Not difficult at all!

Comment: There are ways to do it more securely (just date of birth isn't enough. I know plenty of people's dates of birth who I shouldn't be allowed to find out about their visa status), but the short answer is that consulates aren't really there to serve you, the visa applicant, they're there to serve the interests of their country, and spending time and money to give more information to impatient foreigners generally doesn't rank high on the national priority list. The incentive is to provide good customer service only insofar as it can advance their national interest to promote tourism and business.

Answer (score 11):

Typically the visa centres are overworked and they do not have the bandwidth to deal with incessant questions "is my visa done already?" two hours later "what about now?". It sucks I know, but there's nothing to do but wait. First hand experience: I needed to wait several days for the paper to arrive in mail after the online app switched to "decision made" on my three year long citizenship application to know what the decision is!

The security concerns would be easy to solve by giving everyone a PIN / password, that's not where the problem is.

Comment: The question is why not they inform whether the decision is +ve or -ve, either through a visa portal, app or phone call? Why wait? Looks the visa centers are understaffed but it is their problem and governments doing lazy job and dont want to work hard. They can also pay to recruit more employees. I am sorry i dont mean to be rude, its just that i hate visas and waiting even more.